# Is there a way to enforce the existence of a static member in a child class in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, static

For a tile-based game I'm using different classes to describe the behaviour of the different tile types. They (obviously) derive from a base class. Now I have the problem that sometimes I need to figure out whether the player has enough funds to pay for an upgrade to a certain tile type.

Since the cost of a tile type remains the same all the time, it would seem to make sense to make that static. Unfortunately, C# does not seem to allow the use of abstract classes or interfaces to enforce the existence of such a static field in a child class.

My "solution" was to get this data using reflection, but it seems to me rather ugly and potentially dangerous, since I might forget the static field in one of the child classes, which would bring down the whole thing …

The following code snippet is what I currently have; `AllowedUpdates` is a `List<System.Type>` containing the types a tile can be upgraded to.

```
foreach (Type t in AllowedUpdates) {

    // Get the Action Point Cost
    FieldInfo fi = t.GetField ("actionPointCost", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    int cost = (int)fi.GetValue (null);

    // Check for any requirements
    bool requirementsFulfilled;
    try {
        // Get the static method that checks the necessary requirements.
        MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod ("CheckRequirements", new Type[] { typeof(Dictionary<string, ProtoObject>) });
        object[] arguments = { neighbourFields };

        // Invoke this method
        object returnValue = mi.Invoke (null, arguments);
        requirementsFulfilled = (bool)returnValue;
    } catch (ArgumentNullException) {
        // This type has no special requirements, pass it.
        requirementsFulfilled = true;
    } catch (NullReferenceException) {
        // No requirements needed, pass it.
        requirementsFulfilled = true;
    }
}
```

There must be a better way to do that. Is there a design pattern I overlooked?

Comment: Why not define the protected (non-abstract) **static** field in the abstract base class?

Comment: That might prevent the exceptions, but is dangerous since it could return wrong values, since every class should have its own specific cost. Because of that, I guess I prefer exceptions, as they immediately tell me that there is something missing in my code ...

Comment: You've already embraced reflection by choosing a List<Type> as your data structure. I think the design decision you really need to revisit here is "an upgrade is represented by an instance of Type". That seems bizarre to me. Why isn't an upgrade represented by an instance of the class Upgrade, which can have whatever properties you desire? It seems like you are using a *mechanism* of the *runtime* to represent the *semantics of a game*, which is a bizarre use of the type mechanisms.

Comment: First, let me explain that I'm a student at an art school, and I've never had proper training in programming, so pretty much everything I know about programming and/or C# is self-taught. So, please excuse my skewed assumptions and stupid questions ...

Comment: (cont.) I assumed that it would make sense OO-wise having all information about one tile type collected in one class. Putting some of the information into another class might be a better idea in this case – but how would I add checks for additional requirements that might exist in some tile types and define where they can be placed (which is now done by CheckRequirements())?

Comment: First off, don't worry about "stupid" questions; everyone started at the beginning at some point. Your original question is entirely reasonable. Second, essentially your new question boils down to "how do I do OO design?" That's a *hard* problem and there is no one right answer to it. If you want ideas on more OO ways to design your application, I'd open another question rather than try to have that conversation in comments.

Comment: And finally, to address your actual specific question "is there a design pattern I overlooked?" consider looking at the "strategy pattern", or more specifically the "policy-based design" pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design - this is quite a difficult and complex pattern to wrap your head around, and I'm not personally a fan of template programming, but it might give you some insights.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot enforce, either by an abstract base class or an interface, the existence of a `static` member on any derived class.

Reflection is not your best bet here.  Reconsider your usage of `static` classes in this case.  You might make the cost of a tile type an `abstract` read-only property.  Derived classes will be forced to implement the property.

```
public abstract int ActionPointCost { get; }
```

Comment: Seems like the natural solution to this problem. It also allows a class to inherit this property, if its parent already has it (`abstract` implies you have a base class and direct children - you might have other hierarchy, so you aren't really forcing each class implement it, but that's probably better anyway).

Comment: So if I want to get the cost of (hypothetical) upgrade, I'd use `Activator.CreateInstance(t)`, get the value and destroyed the instance again? (Just checking whether I got that right)

Comment: You shouldn't need `Activator.CreateInstance(t)` unless all you have is a string representing the class name.  Otherwise, it's just `new SomeClassInstance().ActionPointCost`.

Comment: The `foreach` loop is iterating through items of a List<Type>. I was under the impression that something like `new item()`, even with an `item` of type Type, would not work.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.  You would either need to instantiate an instance and use an instance field/property (which could possibly be faster than the reflection you are currently doing).  Or you can keep a `Dictionary<Tile, int>` that stores the value you need.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor metadata about tiles to another class hierarchy where you have things like cost etc.

Answer (score 0):

No. `Interfaces` and `Abstract classes` don't allow you to enforce that.

The reason is they are attached to instances of these classes than definitions of them. There is a good post by `Eric Lippert` on this but I can't find that link right now.

One way I think you could enforce is using `Reflection` on startup of your application. If every class that must have a specific static member does not have it, fail the application.

Other way could be using post-build action to check these constraints like `Code Contracts` do.

Comment: Aha, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/06/14/calling-static-methods-on-type-variables-is-illegal-part-one.aspx

Comment: Just to make the first comment clear, Eric Lippert is well respected, but isn't considered a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You came to the conclusion that a static field is the right design choice for this problem, but the implementation consists of very messy reflection to force the acceptance of your design choice.

I would argue that if the implementation becomes messy for no gain other than "it seems it should", then the design is wrong.

Make it a read-only instance field that must be set by the constructor. Seriously, you'll save yourself a headache.